# Changing the background color of the title block of an extended twig template

Tags: html, css, twig

I have a twig template used for Bootstrap popovers. The code is:

```
span class="popover-wrapper {% block wrapper_class %}{% endblock %}">
  <button
      type="button"
      class="btn-link popover-link {% block link_class %}{% endblock %}"
      tabindex="0"
      role="button"
      data-toggle="popover"
      data-placement="bottom"
      data-title="{% block title %}{% endblock %}"
      >{% block link_text %}{% endblock %}</button>
  <div class="popover-inner-content {% block content_class %}{% endblock %}">
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
  </div>
</span>
```

when extending this template into another `html.twig` view,

```
{% embed 'fragments/popover.html.twig' %}
    {% block link_class %}more-sections{% endblock %}
    {% block link_text %}
         <span class="fa fa-info-circle"></span>

    {% endblock %}
    {% block title %}<div>Contact Info</div>{% endblock %}
    {% block content %} .......
```

When adding `style="background-color: blue;"` to the title div, it disables the popover appear/disappear functionality. How can I alter the backgrond color of the popover Title section>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are breaking the `HTML` by using double quotes inside your title tag.

```
<button data-title="<div style="background-color: blue;">Contact Info</div>">...</button>
```

You could solve this by using single quotes

```
{% block title %}<div style='background-color: blue;'>Contact Info</div>{% endblock %}
```

Comment: thank you. why does using double quotes break the HTML? They are being used in other tags and works fine

Comment: The quote of your div style is closing the opening quote of your data-title attribute